# nuxtserverinit and user login

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, nuxt-auth, nuxtserverinit

I'm working on a nuxt app and need to get data from an api. Data only needs to be served to logged in user. In my vuex store index.js, I wrote the following code:

```js
async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
  if (this.$auth.loggedIn) {
    await Promise.all([
      (async () => {
        const response = await this.$axios.get('api/all/users')

        commit('setUsers', response.data)
      })(),
      (async () => {
        const response = await this.$axios.get('api/all/teams')

        commit('setTeams', response.data)
      })(),
      (async () => {
        const response = await this.$axios.get('api/all/clubs')

        commit('setClubs', response.data)
      })(),
    ])
  }
},
```

The following works, and loads the data on refresh. However - when a user is logging in, the nuxtserverinit wont actually fire, since there's no page reload. What's the proper way to deal with that?

Comment: Do you need this handling on a specific page, or accross the app?

Comment: Across the app, which then data is managed in the vuex store.

Comment: *since there's no page reload*, then use `window.location = '/'` on sign in, it's normal to send someone somewhere upon login, it wont feel buggy to the user

Comment: Either the approach @LawrenceCherone suggested, or you dispatch some store actions to load the data, after the login was successful.

Answer (score 2):

So thanks to your help, what I did for now is dispatching the store actions right after login. So in my login page, I did:

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions(['getTeams', 'getUsers', 'getClubs']),
  loginUser(loginInfo) {
    this.$auth
      .loginWith('local', {
        data: loginInfo,
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.getTeams()
        this.getUsers()
        this.getClubs()
      })
  },
},
```

This won't require a page reload, so will still be fast, and will only load the data after a user logged in.

Comment: What if user reloads the page, the approach you applied still works to load all the data from api call?

Comment: Yes, because the nuxtServerInit will do it on reload.